# Which algorithm to apply to calculate the number of possible arrays?

Tags: algorithm

We have to calculate the number of possible arrays `B` of length `N`, having `M` requirements. (the max of `M` is `20 * 20`)

`1<=N<=20`

`1<=M<=400`

Each requirement is of the form : `x1,y1,z1` : `maximum(B[x1],B[y1])=z1` ,which means maximum of `B[x1]` and `B[y1]` should be z1.

`1<=x1,y1<=20,`

`1<=z1<=1+e8` (or the max of B is less than 1+e8)

Given integer `N` and `M` requirements, how to calculate the number of possible arrays `B`?

Note : This is how array `B` looks like : `B[1],B[2],B[3],....B[20]`.

Comment: Hi there, which software are you using to try to solve this problem - there will be a tag for this? What is your current code?

Comment: My problem has different constraints and the answer given there is not satisfactory.

Comment: can you use a more explicit example? what is b in maximum(b[x1],b[y1])=z1?

Comment: Question has been edited.